# Show that there is a single real number θ such that $h(z)=e^{iz}k(z)$ for any $z$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $h$ and $k$ be complex valued functions each analytic on an open set containing the closed unit disk $B =\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \hspace{5pt} |\hspace{5pt} |z| \leq 1 \rbrace$, and suppose that neither function has zeros in $B$. Assume that $|h(z)|=|k(z)|$ for all $z$ with $|z|=1$. Show that there is a single real number $\theta$ such that $h(z)=e^{i\theta}k(z)$ for all $z \in B$.

I am not sure where to start on this one

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $h/k$ is zero free in $B$ and has modulus $1$ on the boundary. How many such functions are there?